# Where to find Spreecommerce community forum and extension registry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am trying to find the extension Registry and the community forum for Spree commerce.

1. [This](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/extensions_tutorial.html) extension tutorial links to pages that dont exist. ex: There are no extensions to choose from here
2. The community link directs to this webpage https://spreecommerce.com/storefront, which itself is pretty confusing since its a marketing landing page with lots of links to itself.

Can anyone point to the spree extensions and community forums where I can post questions related to Spree commerce?

Comment: Extensions available on github: https://github.com/spree-contrib

Answer (score 1):

There's no more an official extensions list page. The best way to find an extension if searching on github.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in their wiki page, they have a link to their development road map https://github.com/spree/spree/wiki/Spree-Commerce-development-roadmap-2016. With the new maintainers they have opened up a slack forum which I would highly recommend joining  http://slack.spreecommerce.com/. They have started a couple of channels for integrations, moving magento to spree, and also general support topics.